# SQLAlchemy using `label` on columns inside `load_only`

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, label, alias

How would one go about aliasing columns of a table loaded using `joinedload`? My approach was to chain my `joinedload` with `load_only` like this,

```
session.query(TableA) \
    .options(joinedload(TableA.table_b)
             .load_only(TableB.colA.label('col_a_alias'))
            ) \
    .all()
```

However, I get the following error: `TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined`.

The reason I need this is because based on a condition, I want to overwrite the values of TableB.col_a_alias with the values of TableB.colA. This can be achieved by iterating over the objects after the query and setting the attributes manually. However, it would be much more efficient if I could alias the columns to the name of the columns I want to overwrite. I would need to do this inside the options() call because I am dumping the results in a Marshmallow Schema that expects nested objects.

---

## Answer

The solution was to use [Query-time SQL expressions as mapped attributes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#query-time-sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `load_only` controls which attributes of a *model object* are loaded by the query, and so label does not really make sense.

Comment: Essentially, based on a condition, I want to overwrite the values of `TableB.col_a_alias` with the values of `TableB.colA`. I can achieve this by iterating over the objects after the query and setting the attributes manually. However, it would be much more efficient if I could alias the columns to the name of the columns I want to overwrite. I would need to do this inside the `options()` call because I am dumping the results in a Marshmallow Schema that expects nested objects.

Comment: Sounds a bit like you might be after this: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#query-time-sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes

Comment: That is genius! It offers exactly the kind of flexibility I am looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: Great, if you have time please write a self-answer describing the end result. The question itself could maybe also be augmented with what you added in comments.